# why my / partition showing full?

Tags: linux

my / partition is showing 100% full. i have cheked that my home dir is showing 386GB free. can any one show me how to free the / partition.
below is my current partitions

```
[root@mainserver ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       50G   45G  2.1G  96% /
tmpfs                 1.9G  276K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   38M  422M   9% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
                      405G  7.9G  377G   3% /home
[root@mainserver ~]#
```

/ partition is showing only 2.1GB available.

Answer (score 0):

Look for extraneous files under the / file system:

```
cd /
ls -l
```

Do you see extra files?
If not, check under subdirectories directly on the root partition.

That means- check all subdirectories but not under /dev, /boot nor /home.

If you donT recognize files which you can delete, you will need to post output from "ls -l" and maybe we can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

The partition that your root is mounted on is only 50GB. Your home directory is mounted on a much larger partition.

Either delete things from your root (careful, only delete things you *know* aren't essential to the system), or resize the partition using a tool such as GParted.

Answer (score 0):

manually deleting files from / is a bad idea. use your package manager to remove unneeded software.
you could use gparted to resize your partitions so that root has more and home has less, but it is a time consuming and potentially risky process.

Comment: Yes, of course use the package manager to delete software packages.  However, large log files can be manually truncated or deleted.  And if large log files do exist, they should be analysed before "making space".